# Call function after function return

Tags: php

i have the folowing situation:
I have a function "foo" and want the the foo-return the function bar sould be call. Here a little example what i mean:

```
function foo() {
     echo "FOO";
     return "1";
}
function bar() {
    echo "BAR";
}
echo foo();
```

And the output should be display this

> FOO
>   1
>   BAR

All this in PHP!!!
Have anyone a idea how to can realise this WITHOUT call `bar()` in after each `foo()`?

Comment: you can call bar() in return of foo() function - `return bar();`

Comment: you want to see BAR, but dont want to call function printing it? ))

Comment: You can not call a function after a `return` statement.

Comment: @roberto06 - actually you can, using `finally` - but in this case, this seems like an nasty hack..

Comment: @Philipp I didn't know that, I just had a look, my God is it dirty...

Comment: @roberto06 it isn't dirty at all in any normal usecase (closing handles, etc..). It starts getting dirty, if you do something with side effects or change the return value, etc

Comment: @Philipp I meant in this case ;)

Answer (score 2):

You only need to return the call of the function like so:

```
function foo() {
    echo "FOO";
    return bar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you have got two functions then, just add `foo()` like the following:

```
function bar(){
foo();
echo "BAR";
}
```

And remove the return statement from `foo()` function. or write `return 0;`

**Updated:**

You can keep the return function in `foo()`.

Comment: Since, earlier the return statement wasn't returning any value. That's why I suggested you to remove it. But it's fine if you keep it. It will still work until unless the function returns a value. But the return statement must be written at the end.

Answer (score 0):

What you want isn't possible that way. What you actually ask for is, to automatically execute an statement, after you leave the function AND after you called echo.

Calling an statement after `return is possible` using `finally`, but it would be easier (and cleaner) to store the result of calling something else and return it later.

```
function b() {
    echo "bar";
    return 2;
}

function a() {
    try {
        echo "foo";
        return b();
    }
    finally {
        echo "finally";
    }
}

echo a();
```

What you really should do, to get your result is just call `bar`, after you called `foo`.

```
echo foo();
bar();
```